# What would you call pairs of numbers that sum up to a particular number?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, mathematics

When I was in KG, I'd to study lists like these ones—

```
0+5=5     ||    5-0=5
1+4=5     ||    6-1=5
2+3=5     ||    7-2=5
3+2=5     ||    8-3=5
4+1=5     ||    9-4=5
5+0=5     ||    . . .
```

My (non-native) math teacher at that time labelled them as something along the lines of "Addition X table" or "Subtraction X table". And that word/phrase (which X stands for) is a very easy one, something that every child should understand.

It's much like a factor pair—`4x25=100`, `1x100=100`—only except that it's a plus or minus sign instead of the multiplication sign.

I've searched all my preschool textbooks, but found nothing. At last I resorted to Google, but still no luck. So the word or the whole concept must not be standard. Note that I'm a non-native English speaker and I come from a non-native English speaking country as well. So there's the possibility that the word/phrase isn't grammatical or contextually appropriate.

Comment: Sum pairs.. .. ?

Comment: @Claire And if the pair subtract?

Comment: I'm not aware of any term that would be commonly known to, say, young children just learning addition and subtraction. You might try asking on [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com); if there is such a term, someone there will know it. If I were going to make up a term, maybe something like "constituent pairs".

Comment: Well, I dunno. Can you consider it adding or summing a negative number? Example 6 + (-1)? I don't know what to do about zero.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Mathematics SE.

Comment: I’m something of a mathematician, and a native English speaker (USA), and I’m not familiar with any such term.   Also, “factor pair” is not common terminology.   That said, are you looking for “inverse”, or a form of “complement” or “supplement”?

Comment: @Scott I wasn't careful enough. Deleting my comment. Thanks.

Comment: The OP's question concerns restricted partitions of a positive integer into two parts, with each part being either zero or a positive integer.  I'm not aware of a single word to describe this. Partitions usually involve partitioning a positive integer into other positive integers with no restrictions. Example of 4: 4, 3+1, 2+2, 2+1+1, 1+1+1+1. Estimating the number of unrestricted partitions of n as N becomes large is a famous problem in mathematics. Hardy and Ramanujan.

Comment: I’m not sure whether the restriction to non-negative integers is an essential part of the question, or simply a reflection of the fact that the OP is relating an event from kindergarten, before negative numbers and fractions were taught.  That said, what you’re talking about sounds like equivalence classes.  We define equivalence relations — the best known example is modulo.  Two integers *a* and *b* are equivalent modulo 5 (for example) if (and only if) *(a-b)* is a multiple of 5.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  This gives rise to five equivalence classes: one of them is {..., -9, -4, 1, 6, 11, ...}; another is {..., -8, -3, 2, 7, 12, ...}; and obviously {..., -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, ...}.  Similarly, we can define an equivalence relation between ordered pairs: *(a,b)≡(c,d)* iff *a+b=c+d*.  Under this equivalence relation, { (0,5), (1,4), (2,3), (3,2), (4,1), (5,0) } is an equivalence class.  But this would not have been discussed in kindergarten.

Comment: @Scott Agreed. Not in kindergarten. Partitions concerns how many piles into which you can divide 5 sticks. Restricted partitions would add the requirement of no more than two piles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Addend(s)

> a number added to another

([M -W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/addend))

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays they are often called ***number bonds***.

For example

> Number bonds are also often referred to as 'number pairs'. They are simply the pairs of numbers that make up a given number.  (https://www.theschoolrun.com/what-are-number-bonds)